# Uncaught error unexpected token (

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I'm getting an error `Uncaught error unexpected token (` in `script` tag on string with `for` loop

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var offer_foto_index = 'slide_offer_preview_1';
   var slide_offer_preview_ = [];
   var photo_array = <%= @photos.to_json.html_safe %>;
   var offer_foto = {
     for(var i = 0; i < <%= @photos.length %>; i++) {
       slide_offer_preview_[i] = photo_array[i];
     }
   }
</script>
```

I need an `offer_photo` variable which should contain arrays `slide_offer_preview_1`, `slide_offer_preview_2`, `slide_offer_preview_3` etc.

Where did I make a mistake? Thanks!

Comment: you defined an object `offer_foto` with no properties, instead, you put an instruction, that's not permitted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer based on your comment: "...I need a offer_photo variable. It should contain array like slide_offer_preview_1, slide_offer_preview_2 etc."

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var offer_foto_index = 'slide_offer_preview_1';
   var slide_offer_preview_ = [];
   var photo_array = <%= @photos.to_json.html_safe %>;
   var offer_foto = {};
   for(var i = 0; i < <%= @photos.length %>; i++) {
     offer_photo['slide_offer_preview_' + i] = photo_array[i];
   }
</script>
```

Or if you need it to be in one array within "offer_foto" object:

```
var offer_foto = {};
offer_foto.slide_offer_preview_ = [];
for(var i = 0; i < <%= @photos.length %>; i++) {
  offer_photo.slide_offer_preview_[0] = photo_array[i];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing what your actual rendered code looks like, this will be difficult. But my guess is you should be using `photo_array` instead of `@photos`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var offer_foto_index = 'slide_offer_preview_1';
   var slide_offer_preview_ = [];
   var photo_array = <%= @photos.to_json.html_safe %>;
   //var offer_foto = { - I've commented this because you don't need it...
     for(var i = 0; i < photo_array.length; i++) {
       slide_offer_preview_[i] = photo_array[i];
     }
   //}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for helping, but I need a `offer_photo` variable. It should contain array like `slide_offer_preview_1`, `slide_offer_preview_2` etc.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I can use loop inside `var`

Comment: I think you need to rewrite your question. This isn't explained in your post.